# Converting months to numbers to use in sort algorithm - possible array limitation?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

As part of the program I am creating for one of my assignments, there is a text file with a list of months (600 to be precise) and these have to be sorted in chronological order without built in sort methods. I've had no issue importing the months and converting them to numbers, however outputting the contents of the number array only outputs numbers 6, 11 and 12 before just outputting 0s. I thought this could be a limitation of the array size but it doesn't explain why only 3 numbers are being outputted.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[]args){
    Console.WriteLine("Unsorted Array:");
    string[] monArray = File.ReadAllLines("Month_1.txt");
    int[] numArray = new int[12] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int[] monthNums = new int[monArray.Length];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < monArray.Length; i++){Console.WriteLine(monArray[i]);}
    foreach (string month in monArray){
        switch (month){
            case "January":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[1];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "February":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[2];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "March":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[3];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "April":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[4];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "May":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[5];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "June":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[6];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "July":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[7];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "August":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[8];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "September":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[9];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "October":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[10];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "November":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[11];
            counter++;
            break;
            case "December":
            monthNums[counter] = numArray[12];
            counter++;
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < monthNums.Length; i++){Console.WriteLine(monthNums[i]);}
    }
```

Comment: You will have to explain your strategy here. I don't see any code that does any sorting. Your code simply converts the Month names to some numbers. BTW, you are missing a curly brace after the `switch` ends. I can't post an answer, since I don't know what format is the output expected for a given sample input.

Comment: @Vikhram The sorting code isn't necessary for this part, I'm just having issues converting the months to numbers.

Comment: You already have the month names converted to numbers and and stored in `monthNums`. As I asked earlier, you should explain your requirements with input and output, for us to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning `monthNums[counter]` to the value in the corresponding `numArray`, and you're incrementing `counter` on every iteration, so it will increment 600 times.

I think what you really want to do is lookup the index of the month to update from `numArray`, and then add one to the value of that item in `monthNums`, which can be done using the `++` operator.

Also, remember that arrays are `0` based, which means that the first item in at index `[0]`. Your `monthNums` array has `12` items, which would be indexes `0` - `11`.

```
// Initialize the array starting at '0', not '1'...
int[] numArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

// For any given month string, look up it's corresponding index in numArray
// And use that value for the index to increment the count in monthNums
switch (month)
{         
    case "January":
        monthNums[numArray[0]]++;
        break;
    case "February":
        monthNums[numArray[1]]++;
        break;
    case "March":
        monthNums[numArray[2]]++;
        break;

    // continue this pattern...
}
```

Also, since the value of every item in `numArray` is it's index, you really don't need this array - you only need `monthNums`...

```
switch (month)
{
    case "January":
        monthNums[0]++;
        break;
    case "February":
        monthNums[1]++;
        break;
    case "March":
        monthNums[2]++;
        break;

    // Continue this pattern ...
}
```

---

An even better solution might be to create an `enum` for the months, where the value of each month corresponds to the index you want to update, and then you can use `enum.TryParse` to get the index. By default, the first item in an enum is `0`, and each item after it increments by `1`, so we don't need to explicitly assign any values in the enum.

The enum would look like:

```
enum Month
{
    January, February, March, April, May, June, July,
    August, September, October, November, December
}
```

And then you can parse it like so:

```
foreach (string month in monArray)
{
    Month convertedMonth;

    // If the value of 'month' from our string array can be converted to a Month, 
    // update the count in the corresponding array index
    if (Enum.TryParse(month, true, out convertedMonth))
    {
        monthNums[(int)convertedMonth]++;
    }
}
```

Here's a working example of a program that populates an array with 600 random month names (to simulate your file), then updates the second array with counts for each month, and finally outputs the results:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Populate our 'file' with 600 random month names:
    var rnd = new Random();
    var monArray = new string[600];
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
    {
        monArray[i] = ((Month) rnd.Next(0, 12)).ToString();
    }

    // The array to hold counts for each month
    int[] monthNums = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    // Read each string, if it converts to a month, increment our counter
    foreach (string month in monArray)
    {
        Month convertedMonth;

        if (Enum.TryParse(month, true, out convertedMonth))
        {
            monthNums[(int) convertedMonth]++;
        }
    }

    // Output the counts for each month
    for (int i = 0; i < monthNums.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{(Month) i} count: {monthNums[i]}");
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

[image]

For just converting a string to a month, the following `enum` and method will do the trick:

```
enum Month
{
    January, February, March, April, May, June, July,
    August, September, October, November, December
}

private static int ConvertMonthToInt(string month)
{
    Month temp;

    if (!Enum.TryParse(month, true, out temp))
    {
        // Do something here if the string isn't a month
        return -1;
    }

    return (int)temp;
}
```

Comment: I should have specified that I don't need to count the frequencies, I just need to convert the months to numbers to sort them.

Comment: What are you trying to sort? The lines in a text file? And then do what with it? Your question is a little unclear, and your code shows no sorting algorithm, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Isn't the output above displaying the sorted counts of months from a text file?

Comment: The code above is intended to convert each of the 600 months from an array into their corresponding numbers to then be sorted so they can be converted back to months and displayed in chronological order. The sorting algorithm isn't an issue.

Comment: Added at the bottom the basics for converting a `string` month to an `int` using the `enum` and a method. The default case for the enum is `January = 0`, but you can set it (and any other value in the enum) to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying, but seems like this:

1. Read the months, one line at a time and convert them to a number.

   1. These numbers should map conveniently to slots 1 - 12 of an array
   2. So store the count of how many times they occur in this array
2. Now read the count array sequentially (i.e. sorted order), and hopefully convey the count to the output along with the order.

There are a bunch of things I would avoid from what you are doing.

1. Keep your coding extensible for

   1. Different locales (non gregorian calendar) if applicable
   2. Handle case insensitive inputs
   3. Handle short month names instead of full month names.
2. Don't use a case statement. Try using an `if` statement or a `Dictionary` to handle based on above answer.
3. I am very confused with what you are doing with `monthNums` and `numArray`. I think the `numArray` is probably redundant.

Below is how I wrote the code guessing some requirements and trying to stick with your ideas.

```
static string[] MonthNames = new string[12]; // store the names of the month as found in the file to print out later

static int GetMonthNumber(string month) {
    // Accommodating short month names and case sensitivity
    // TODO: handle locale issues for case and month names, if applicable
    var lowerMonth = month.ToLower();
    int value;
    if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("jan"))
        value = 0;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("feb"))
        value = 1;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("mar"))
        value = 2;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("apr"))
        value = 3;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("may"))
        value = 4;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("jun"))
        value = 5;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("jul"))
        value = 6;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("aug"))
        value = 7;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("sep"))
        value = 8;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("oct"))
        value = 9;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("nov"))
        value = 10;
    else if (lowerMonth.StartsWith("dec"))
        value = 11;
    else
        throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown month: {lowerMonth}", nameof(lowerMonth));

    MonthNames[value] = month;

    return value;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Unsorted Array:");

    string[] monArray = File.ReadAllLines("Month_1.txt"); /*new string[] { "January", "March", "January", "sept" };*/

    int[] monthNums = new int[11];

    for (int i = 0; i < monArray.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(monArray[i]);

    foreach (string month in monArray)
        monthNums[GetMonthNumber(month)]++;

    for (int i = 0; i < monthNums.Length; i++) {
        if (monthNums[i] != 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"{MonthNames[i],-10} : ({monthNums[i]} times)");
    }

}
```

Comment: Almost correct with the requirements, except I'm not counting the frequencies, I just want to convert each month to it's corresponding number (Jan -> 1, etc) and sort the list chronologically.